# mediaBytesTransferred in video js on ios device

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js, http-streaming, hls.js

I have stream video in videoJs.
In order to find out how much traffic is used by my site visitors, I want to measure Total bytes of content downloaded.
I installed video js http streaming(vhs) and With vhs I am able to adjust buffer size through an mediaBytesTransferred property.

```
this.bufferedSize = +this.player?.tech()?.vhs.stats.mediaBytesTransferred;
```

It works on all browsers except iOS browsers.
The vhs is undefined in iOS.
According to this link on the Internet(https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/issues/1102), ios uses native players and vhs is not supported in ios.
I have searched for another solution, but cannot find one.

Answer (score 0):

It's still the case that you can only have native playback on iOS and it will be unless ans until it supports Media Source Extensions.